# insert values _at_ specific locations in numpy array (np.insert done right?)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose that I have a `numpy.array` of values, say

`values = np.array([0, 3, 2, 4, 6])`

and a `numpy.array` of indices, say

`idces = np.array([1, 3, 5])`.

I want to obtain an array which has a given value, say `-1`, in the positions of the idces, and the other elements distributed in the remaining locations. So in the case above I want to obtain

`np.array([0, -1, 3, -1, 2, -1, 4, 6])`.

This looks like the task of `np.insert`, except that the latter inserts values before the *values* at the specified indexes, rather than *at* the specified indexes (and the two coincide only when there is only one index).

So the best I could come up with is

`np.insert(values, idces - np.arange(len(idces)), -1)`.

This is still better than creating an array with `-np.ones`, calculating the indices of the `idces` and then using `np.put`... but I was wondering: is there any cleaner way?

Comment: If you are looking for a built-in, I don't see any or even more compact way. Using `array-initialization` could be one way (for performance), but that won't be a one-liner.

Comment: Your use of `insert` is exactly right for the purpose, and it isn't messy. Having another NumPy method for `insert` in terms of post-insertion indices would be confusing, so it's no surprise there isn't one.

Comment: @6'whitemale OK, makes sense... still, I'm curious to know if there's any plausible argument for having ``insert`` not behaving like this by default. Seems to me both more useful and easier to describe.

Answer (score 1):

Insertion is best thought of in terms of *offsets*, which enumerate not the array elements but the gaps between (or before/after) them:

[image: offsets]

The documentation of [`np.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) describes it as "the index or indices before which values is inserted" which is only approximately right. An offset can be equal to `len(arr)` (end of array) even though `arr[len(arr)]` throws out-of-bounds error.

For example, `np.insert([3, 1, 4, 1, 5], [1, 3, 3, 5], [0, 0, 0, 0])` means: put one zero at the gap numbered 1, two others at the gap numbered 3, and the last one at the end. The result is `[3, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 1, 5, 0]`.

Some advantages of this enumeration over specifying post-insertion indices of new elements:

1) It's easier to insert a bunch of elements at one place: `np.insert(arr, [3]*values.size, values)` inserts the array `values` at the 3rd offset.

2) It's easier to interlace two arrays, with `np.insert(arr, np.arange(values.size), values)`

3) It's easier to control whether an insertion point is valid; the validity does not depend on how many elements are being inserted.

The case when you know post-insertion indices `idces` is easy enough to handle, as you did with

```
np.insert(values, idces - np.arange(len(idces)), -1)
```

[Related issue on NumPy tracker](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9274).